# Selecting custom indexes in array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an nested array that's a mix of words and numbers. It looks like this **conceptually**. I need to process only numbered indexes such as `15` and `28`. I guess this means that I can't use a `foreach` loop (or is there a way I could). How would you do this?

```
myarray = (

   someindex = (
     field1 = 
     field2 = 
   );

   15 = (
     field1 = 
     field2 = 
   );

   28 = (
     field1 = 
     field2 = 
   );

   anothertext = (
     field1 = 
     field2 = 
   );

);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
foreach($myarr as $key => $item)
{
    if(is_int($key))
    {
        // Do processing here
    }
}
```

Yes, that will loop through *every* item in the array, so if you wanted to process the other items separately, you could just add in an `else` block.

---

**Edit:** Changed `is_numeric` to `is_int`. See comments for explanation.

Comment: Note that a string containing a numeric value will also be processed now, if that is a problem, use is_int (perhaps with is_float if you want non-ints as well) instead.

Comment: I've never heard of `ctype_digit`. Time to go do some research!

Answer (score 4):

You can use foreach

```
foreach($myarray as $key=>$value)
{
    if(is_int($key))
    {
           //process the entry as you want
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a [`FilterIterator`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/class.filteriterator.php) with foreach:

```
class IntKeyFilterIterator extends FilterIterator {
    public function accept() {
        return is_int(parent::key());
    }
}

$it = new IntKeyFilterIterator(new ArrayIterator($array));
foreach ($it as $value) {
    // Will only have those with int keys
}
```

Comment: Interesting approach. When did PHP get `Iterator` classes? (I don't do much OOP with PHP, too much of our codebase at my company is pre-built, and I usually build other things in my free time.)

Comment: Since PHP 5.1...  See the [SPL Iterators](http://us.php.net/manual/en/spl.iterators.php) and the [Iterator Interface](http://us.php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php)

Answer (score 0):

Another version. Grep the source array for any purely numeric keys, then loop over that result array and do the processing.

```
$keys = preg_grep('/^\d+$/', array_keys($myarray)) {
foreach($keys as $key) {
    doSomething($myarray[$key]);
}
```

Comment: that's (quite a bit) slower, uses more memory and is less readable - I don't see any advantage to this method, actually.

Comment: Just another alternative. Might be more usesable if you're on an older PHP and/or don't have SPL available.